# What model should I use for this weird dataset? (Survey Response attributes)

Tags: regression, logistic, dataset, survey

[image]
Above is a snippet of a dataset I am working with. It is a pull from a research tool presenting a set of many different and distinct attributes that have been sorted into numerous "categories" and "insights", some of which only occur once in the dataset (e.g. "Horror" or "Entertainment Lifestyle" on the far right.) and calculated "composition" and "indexing" percentages compared to the general population and sample "audience".

I would like to make all of the fields with categorical variables into dummy variables and then use one of those dummy variables as a target/independent variable in a logistic regression model. The numerical variables are "composition %" and "index" on the far right.

My question(s) is:
a. would using a logistic regression model even make sense if the target dummy variable only occurs once in the sample dataset? (i.e. there is only one "1" value in the entire field corresponding to the specific category after converting to a dummy variable since the categories are all very unique and the categories I am interested in are very distinct)
b. if I were to use the numerical variables as predictors for this logistic model, would I need to do anything to make the corresponding coefficients more interpretable in model results?
c. Are there any other models that would be more helpful or is this dataset simply not workable from a machine learning standpoint?

I would be grateful for any pointers or ideas or links to similar discussions.